# find position of best value

Tags: python

so I've been given the question of writing code that will find the best value position in a list example would be the best value is the first number on the list then I would want it to return (or make a variable to print it) that would be 0.
the code I have is currently not working and any help would be appreciated

```
temperatures = [4.7, 3, 4.8]
best_position = temperatures[0]
# for each position from 1 to length of list – 1:
for temperature in temperatures[-1]:
    if temperature > best_position:
        best_position = temperature
print(best_position)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently trying to loop on a single element because `temperatures[-1]` means the last element of the list. If you do so, you will get

> TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Since you want the index, you should start by using 0 as your `best_position` for the first element. You should then loop over the whole list because you wan't to compare with all the remaining items in the list. Using `enumerate` gives you the index as well

```
temperatures = [4.7, 3, 4.8]
best_position = 0

for i, temperature in enumerate(temperatures):
    if temperature > temperatures[best_position]:
        best_position = i
print(best_position)
# 2
```

Comment: Hey thank you for replying, that's the original code I came up with however I need it to state the position in the original list. in this example the answer is 4.8 which has an index of "2" I need to get it so what ever the best value is it prints out the index position from the original list.

Comment: I have never even seen "enumerate" before thank you so much